# Use DOM and XPath to make some changes in HTML document

Tags: php, performance, dom, xpath

I intend to make some changes in an HTML document, like remove, replace, append some nodes.

I have several arrays with same structure like the following example

```
$patterns[] = array(
    'xpath'   => '/html/body/div/p',
    'insert'  => $new_a,
    'task'    => 'replace'
);

...

$patterns[] = array(
    'xpath'   => '/html/body/header',
    'insert'  => $new_b,
    'task'    => 'remove'
);
```

and I use the following snippet

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

if ((empty($html) !== true) && ($dom->loadHTML($html) === true))
{
    $dom->formatOutput = true;

    // Use DomXPath
    $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

    // Process Dom changes
    foreach ($patterns as $key => $value)
    {
        $xpath_results = $xpath->query($patterns[$key]['xpath']);

        if ($xpath_results->length) 
        {
            // Assign some values
            $xpath_results = $xpath_results->item(0);
            $task          = $patterns[$key]['task'];
            $replacement   = $patterns[$key]['insert'];

            if ($task != 'remove')
            {
                // Create the replacement
                $newNode = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
                $newNode->appendXML($replacement);
            }

            switch ($task)
            {
                case 'remove':
                    $xpath_results->parentNode->removeChild($xpath_results);
                    break;
                case 'replace':
                    $xpath_results->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $xpath_results);
                    break;
                case 'append':
                    $xpath_results->appendChild($newNode);
                    break;
                case 'prepend':
                    $xpath_results->parentNode->insertBefore($newNode, $xpath_results);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Save Dom 
    $html = $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
}
```

I would like your expert comments about if this is done the right way. The `foreach` to loop through the array elements, the `switch` to choose what will be done and if the use of `createDocumentFragment` is appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to globally do the right job, using a right way, and I can't see how you could really improve performance.
I only noticed a few bad points:

1. Unless I missed some subtleness, there is a typo in the `case 'append':` branch: it should be using `$xpath_results->**parentNode**`,like others.
2. You didn't take in account a possible error condition at `$newNode->appendXML($replacement);`: it may return `FALSE`, so you should cancel the process in that case.
3. The same applies to a possible wrong value in the `task` index of a pattern: it should be taken in account through the `default:` option of the `switch()`.

In the other hand I would suggest some improvements at the coding level itself, essentially for readability.

1. You're using `foreach ($patterns as $key => $value)`, but then always write `$patterns[$key][...]` so you force PHP to a few more work, while `$value` is never used.
   I suggest to rather use `foreach ($patterns as $value)`, then `$value[...]`.
   (or even more readable `foreach ($patterns as $pattern)`, then `$pattern[...]`)
2. Still for readability I would add a separate variable to clearly distinguish the successive "avatars" of `$xpath_results`, which is first a DOMNodeList then a DOMNode.
   So you could change your DOMNode extraction to `$node = $xpath_results->item(0);`, and all following code becomes much more obvious.
3. Your `// Assing some values`part could be reduced to the `$node` assignation above: the two other variables are only used once so you could merely write `$newNode->appendXML($pattern['insert']);` and `switch ($pattern['task'])`.

So here is my suggestion for the whole snippet after the remarks above:

```
if ($html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    if (!$dom->loadHTML($html)) {
        $error = 'Error while loading source HTML!';
    } else {
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        // Use DomXPath
        $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
        // Process Dom changes
        foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
            $xpath_results = $xpath->query($pattern['xpath']);
            if ($xpath_results->length) {
                $node = $xpath_results->item(0);

                if ($task != 'remove') {
                    // Create the replacement
                    $newNode = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
                    if (!$newNode->appendXML($pattern['insert'])) {
                        $error = "Wrong insert pattern: $pattern['insert']!";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!@$error) {
                    switch ($pattern['task']) {
                        case 'remove':
                            $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
                            break;
                        case 'replace':
                            $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
                            break;
                        case 'append':
                            $node->parentNode->appendChild($newNode);
                            break;
                        case 'prepend':
                            $node->parentNode->insertBefore($newNode, $node);
                            break;
                        default:
                            $error = "Wrong task pattern: $pattern['task']!";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (@$error) {
        // print or return $error...
    } else {
        // Save Dom
        $html = $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
    }
}
```

For the error processing, I arbitrarily choosed one simple option among numerous different possiilities.  You can notice:

1. The `@$error` form: it is a simple and clear way to allow using variables set only in certain cases without having defined them previously.
2. Still for readability, I changed the initial tests into more simple (and sufficient) forms: `if ($html)` and `if (!dom->loadHTML($html))`.

Comment: @cFeed More clean and readable, indeed. I completely ignored the error handling in my snippet :( Corrected now. Thank you very much for your tips.